# Steering Wobble between 60 and 80mph - intermittent (mostly there now)

Tags: vibration, steering-wheel

I am hunting vibrations on my car. All started at early (6000 miles) after a pothole in Italy.

Car is: Alfa Romeo Giulia Veloce (TI) Q4 - Gasoline - year 2020 (facelift)

Milage now: 29800 miles

The car is an AWD with staggered setup. Rear wheel drive constantly, and sometimes front wheels support traction.

After that pothole, cat began giving an intermittent light wobble at 80-95mph (germany is allowed to drive that high)

Over time, and until 25000miles the car became worst there was an come and go shake at 85mph

Visually no issues. I went to a vibration specialist, who uses PicoTech NVH. He found:

1. Front lower RIGHT LCA was vibrating
2. Inner tie rod right had more play than right

Dealer changed under warranty the whole RACK, inner, outer rods + the right lower-front front wheel LCA (It has 2 at lower side) Multilink suspencion.

I took the car and drove it. now the wobble went from 137 to around 120.

I drove from Germany to Greece. (now we are at 30000 miles) and I found one of the newer tires (front right) was having some issue.

I replaced Front tires (PZero Pz4 225/40/19) and I have already from 25000miles also new at back (PZero PZ4 255/35/19)

I checked - 2 weeks ago

- Front system again (no play on anything
- Front wheels and rear wheels for out of round issues (they are perfect)
- New tires are back and front
- Road Force balanced

Still when I drive to that speed, sometimes I have the wooble (about 60-80mph) mostly on 75mph

1.5 week ago I fall into a pothole! and I bent both right rims, the car started shaking more at 60-80mph, now almost always!

I fixed the wheels the next day! road force balanced again! and all pefrect! The road force is Green! the wheels/tires has no obvious visible issues

I also checked front suspension for any issues! no obvious signs
Checked 5 days ago:

- shocks for issues (all give 70-72% on the bench)
- Front and rear Control arms/bushings nothing!
- wheel bearing no play
- Tripod are ok / half shafts - they also replaced one tripod on front right as it was giving a bit of play

did not check yet:

- Runout on Hub
- No clue!

It is freaking strange this happens and moved to lower km/h
Thoughts:

- Can it be the Runflats are causing some short of raisonance vibration and/or
- Brake Rotors are out of round/hub runout to cause this?
- engine mounts?

There is nothing Visible/obvious on the car to show a sign of issues

Way to  produce this:

- hard cornerning or change lane fast, can make this wobble start
- Before accident (pothole) a light braking could make the wobble start too (that makes me think also rotors and/or hub issues)
- Braking more and more, give me a clicking feeling on the steering when breaking but stops when released
- road issue (like entering a bridge) where the car hits a light imperfaction of the road, can also triger it

Felt only on steering, not car body

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the vehicle in question? This information is important, because some vehicles have known issues in certain areas which can help us not only diagnose what's going on, but also give you our best effort at the remedy. You also state the mileage on the car now, if you would please.

Comment: I added the info!